# What is every way a character can gain access to the Wish spell other than magic items?

Tags: dnd-5e, wish

According to what I’ve seen, Arcana clerics, wizards, bards (through the Magical Secrets feature), and sorcerers are the only classes/subclasses that can learn or prepare the *wish* spell.

Are there any other options available to be able to cast the *wish* spell as a caster, without using magic items?

Comment: to be clear, you are asking ways  to be able to have a character *cast* the wish spell correct? So, for example, befriending a wish-granting creature would not be a viable solution to this question correct?

Comment: More generally I guess, I'm confused by what exactly you mean by "gain" the wish spell. Gain access to it but not being able to cast it? Being able to cast it once? Adding it to your spell list? What is your requirement here?

Comment: Sorry, I mean by gaining access to casting the spell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### You've pretty much got them covered

*Wish* only appears on the wizard and sorcerer spell list, and the only other classes that can access those spell lists for level 9 spells are the bard through Magical Secrets and the Arcana Domain of the cleric.

The only other way for a character to gain the effect of *wish* is through Divine Intervention. This cleric feature says:

> Imploring your deity’s aid requires you to use your action. Describe the assistance you seek, and roll percentile dice. If you roll a number equal to or lower than your cleric level, your deity intervenes. The DM chooses the nature of the intervention; the effect of any cleric spell or **cleric domain spell** would be appropriate.

*Wish* could be chosen as the nature of the intervention (in fact, it can even be a domain spell to Arcana Domain clerics via the Arcane Mastery feature, a distinction explored by [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140300/41726))

Comment: It might be ridiculous and too far afield to add this, but you might be able to use wish (perhaps via a djinni) to be able to add wish to your spells.

Comment: Thanks David! And that’s a good idea Rubiksmoose, I figured there was probably an option to use Wish to grant someone else Wish but I feel like that’s rather varied as it’s up to the DM.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose That mini recursion might work.

Comment: "Your wish is granted ! You now have access to Wish but lose access to all your other spells !"